# Cannot aggregate a query which merges two unrelated tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a query which pulls data from two UNRELATED tables (salaries a and employees b) and merges them based on the date month. When I want to add an aggregated column such as count of employees (count(distinct emp_no)), it keeps running the query and then times out...why? I am using MySql workbench.

```
SELECT 
count(distinct b.emp_no) as employees,
month(b.hire_date), 
month(a.to_date)
FROM salaries a, employees b
WHERE month(b.hire_date)=month(a.to_date)
group by 2,3;
```

The goal output would be something like

```
employees|Hire_month|To_month
799      |6         |6
```

Comment: How big are the tables? What indexes do they have? What version of MySQL are you using (5.x or 8.x)?

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Please provide sample data and desired results and  clear explanation of what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: Joining two unrelated tables is rarely a good idea. Not only for perfomance reasons. I agree with Gordon - It doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: What do you mean unrelated? You are doing a join on month(b.hire_date)=month(a.to_date), although old fashioned it is still a join.

Comment: Seconding the "doesn't make sense" evaluation; it might help us help you if you describe in a plain sentence what you are trying to do.

Comment: So many things wrong with this query.  What do you expect to get from joining 2 unrelated tables?  Reading an Introduction to Relational Database book would be a good start.  `JOIN` has been around for over 25 years, so start using it.  `GROUP BY 2, 3` is a really bad idea.